# How to average a range of values in a pandas data frame column?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I want to average the values in rows 5-8 in the column Age, how would I do this?

```
   Name  Age  
0    x    5
1    y    7
2    z    2
3    p    9
4    q    12
5    r    6
6    s    5
7    t    1
8    u    13
9    v    10
```

Comment: Rows by row number, or by row/index id (it may not matter here, but it can matter elsewhere)? For the latter: `df.loc[5:8, 'Age'].mean()` should do the trick.

Comment: index id. Also that worked.